# How to suppress asm.js compilation message?

Tags: javascript, asm.js

When using asm.js code some browsers emit a compilation message. This one:

> Successfully compiled asm.js code (loaded from cache in 201ms)

Is there a way to suppress this message?

Comment: Where does this emit? In console?

Comment: yes in the console, when there's asm.js code present

Comment: You want to prevent this message in all your user's consoles?   How many of your users even use the console!?

Comment: I use the console, and don't like to see it cluttered with warnings and non-relevant messages. Feels messy,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message itself is here: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/js/src/js.msg#l357

> ```
> MSG_DEF(JSMSG_USE_ASM_TYPE_OK, 1, JSEXN_WARN, "Successfully compiled asm.js code ({0})")
> ```

And it is emitted here: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/js/src/wasm/AsmJS.cpp#l8718

> ```
> static bool
> SuccessfulValidation(AsmJSParser& parser, UniqueChars str)
> {
>     return parser.warningNoOffset(JSMSG_USE_ASM_TYPE_OK, str.get());
> }
> ```

Which is called here: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/js/src/wasm/AsmJS.cpp#l8877

> ```
>     // Success! Write to the console with a "warning" message.
>     *validated = true;
>     SuccessfulValidation(parser, Move(message));
>     return NoExceptionPending(cx);
> }
> ```

There is no apparent "optionality" in that line, even the comment says that it is going to the console, period.

Otherwise `JSEXN_WARN` has a couple real occurrences only (in [jsexn.h](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/js/src/jsexn.h), [jsexn.cpp](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/js/src/jsexn.cpp) and in [jsapi.h](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/js/src/jsapi.h)), the latter one descibes it as it is practically an exception type which does not break execution and does not have a scary part ("Error:..."): https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/js/src/jsapi.h#l580

> ```
> * JSEXN_WARN is used for warnings in js.msg files (for instance because we
> * don't want to prepend 'Error:' to warning messages). This value can go away
> * if we ever decide to use an entirely separate mechanism for warnings.
> ```

And it is true, most checks for JSEXN_WARN are about skipping the throw of an actual exception, in a `if ( ... || exnType == JSEXN_WARN || ... ) do nothing` fashion, like [here](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/js/src/jsexn.cpp#l631) (just one, ad-hoc example).

I am not sure what you really need, but

> How to supress asm.js compilation message?

Via building your own copy of Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Simple_Firefox_build

Comment: Very good explanation. Unfortunatelly it's useless to me, because I can't make my site's users use a custom build of Firefox. The objetive is just not pollute console with non-relevant messages. 
Let's see if anyone can come with other, more usable solution until the bounty period is over. If not the bounty is yours. 
But by your explanation I don't really think this is possible.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira of course, the build-your-own-Firefox was not a very serious suggestion, just as long as I was looking into the code I did not encounter a higher level to configure this behavior.

Comment: Actually I don't use asm.js directly. I use "SQLite compiled to javascript" project (https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/) that uses asm.js, that shows the message.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I think we both know that the usage of asm.js is what counts, not the location of that usage. However it may be worth mentioning that asm.js is triggered by the "use asm" prologue, which is easy to locate and remove (there should be a couple occurrences only), which reverts AOT compilation to JIT. There will be an impact on performance, especially while the JIT is warming up, but the functionality is expected to be exactly the same as it is with asm.js

Comment: I need all the speed I can get for this task. So I prefer to maintain the message in this case. I only mentioned this as a side comment. Thanks for your idea anyway.

Comment: @​tevemadar as promised the bounty is yours. Thanks for caring enough to look into Firefox source code. Even if I didn't find a solution, your answer deserved it. :)

Comment: @​tevemadar can you just tell me another thing ? When I tried to mark your name SO engine removed the markup. I had to include a zero-width space in order to work. But you didn't include it in my name's markup and the engine didn't remove it. Do you know why ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I am not familiar with most tools and mechanisms around on SO (for example I have not asked a question yet, so I do not even know how an answer is marked), the only thing I can add is that my nickname does not contain obscure nonprintable characters/whitespaces or anything special. Looking/asking around on meta may help, but I really do not know.